# MVC 5 Email Confirmation

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, asp.net-mvc-5

I have been looking at various tutorials and found one which on first glance looks ideal, however I am struggling with a few issues in implementation. Can somebody please help me out with the following issues?

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public Nullable<int> TitleId { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> SexId { get; set; }
    public string Forename { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string ConfirmationToken { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> Active { get; set; }
    public DateTime? JoinDate { get; set; }
}
```

Is NVARCHAR(128) suitable for the field ConfirmationToken?

```
private string CreateConfirmationToken()
{
    return ShortGuid.NewGuid();
}
```

The word `ShortGuid` is underlined in red in Visual Studio 2013 so I'm guessing I'm missing a namespace or class.

```
private void SendEmailConfirmation(string to, string username, string confirmationToken)
{
    dynamic email = new Email("RegEmail");
    email.To = to;
    email.UserName = username;
    email.ConfirmationToken = confirmationToken;
    email.Send();
}
```

In the line `dynamic email = new Email("RegEmail");` the word `Email` is underlined in red. Also can this be modified to use smtp.yahoo.com, port 587 using NetworkCredential and EnableSsl?

```
private bool ConfirmAccount(string confirmationToken)
{
    ApplicationDbContext context = new ApplicationDbContext();
    ApplicationUser user = context.Users.SingleOrDefault(u => u.ConfirmationToken == confirmationToken);
    if (user != null)
    {
        user.Active = true;
        DbSet<ApplicationUser> dbSet = context.Set<ApplicationUser>();
        dbSet.Attach(user);
        context.Entry(user).State = EntityState.Modified;
        context.SaveChanges();

        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

In the line `DbSet<ApplicationUser> dbSet = context.Set<ApplicationUser>();` the section DbSet is underlined in red as is the word `EntityState`.

Please see the original article by Kevin Junghans for any further reference (http://kevin-junghans.blogspot.co.uk/2013/10/adding-email-confirmation-to-aspnet.html).

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Just to get you started ShortGuid is not part of the base classes therefore you need a dependency to the https://www.nuget.org/packages/ShortGuid/ library.

Comment: Thank you, I've installed the package ShortGuid 1.0.0, now the word `ShortGuid` is no longer underlined in red, but the word `NewGuid` is.

Answer (score 0):

Hope I'm not too late ;)
I ran over the exact same problem with the same blog.
You have to install more packages as specified in Andreas' comment.
Run this command in Package Manager Console:

`Install-Package postal -Version 0.9.2`

This will enable you to resolve the Email with the "Postal" reference.

Also your "ShortGuid" problem seems to be resolved if you replace your return statement with this:

`return ShortGuid.NewShortGuid();`

I didn't use the rest of your code, but I suppose you can use more package installs to resolve these as well ;)